# Error(s): source_file.c:5:32: fatal error: ../include/externs.h: No such file or directory #include "../include/externs.h" ^ compilation terminated

Tags: c

I have some C code that, when I try to compile it, gives this error:

```
error:"source_file.c:5:32: fatal error: ../include/externs.h: No such file or directory
#include "../include/externs.h"
          ^
compilation terminated.
```

and this is the first part of my code that has the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../include/externs.h"``
#include "../include/cephes.h"  

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
                 R A N D O M  E X C U R S I O N S  T E S T
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
```

What is going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Remove extra symbols after `"`

Comment: Note that you get that error when you *build* your code, not when you "run" it. And the error messages you show are very easy to understand: The files you `#include` can't be found. Are they in the relative path where you expect them to be?

Comment: The compiler can't find the header file. There's nothing else to it. Except it is a bad idea to use paths in #includes. Better to provide the compiler with all directories it need to search for files in. Modern IDE:s do this automatically.

Comment: I run it in online compiler in internet because i don't have c compiler

Comment: Then how do you know what header files are available, and where? And *which* "online compiler" are you using?

Comment: i run in this site"https://sourcesara.com/tryit_codes/tryit.php?lang=c_gcc"

Comment: i know that i should show header files but i don't know how should i do that

Comment: `What is going wrong` The file `../include/externs.h` is missing and the compiler can't find the file relative to the current compiled file. `how do I fix it?` You provide/create the file in question. I don't understand.